# Run multiple Electron instances based on command line arguments

Tags: electron, multiple-instances

I know we can use app.requestSingleInstanceLock to limit Electron to run a single instance.  But I have a use case, to run multiple Electron instances based on the cmdline arguments, to allow a new instance for each unique arg.  For example,

```
   myelectron.exe http://host1:port1
   myelectron.exe http://host2:port2
   myelectron.exe http://host1:port1
```

The above 3 commands would start 2 instances, 1 for each unique cmdline url.

Questions:

1. How to save app-level user data in Electron across all instances?
   I'd like to keep a list/map for all running instances of unique urls, and remove an entry if its instance was closed.
2. Is there a better way to achieve this use case?

Comment: if you can work with 1 singleton main process and 1 electron browserwindow opened for each different argv, then you can use `requestSingleInstanceLock` and `second-instance` to make it.